# Python aiosqlite override Connection with pysqlcipher3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, python-asyncio, sqlcipher, pysqlcipher

I saw [an example](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/examples/diary.py) of peewee where pysqlcipher was used as the connector for managing a database file rather than the sqlite module. That's great and there's even an [async version of peewee](https://peewee-async.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but I don't need (Or want) to use peewee's object model. In peewee, the connector is initialized like this:

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse.sqlcipher_ext import SqlCipherDatabase

db = SqlCipherDatabase(None)

class Entry(Model):

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

I want to do something similar with [aiosqlite](https://github.com/omnilib/aiosqlite) and [pysqlcipher3](https://github.com/rigglemania/pysqlcipher3) instead of using peewee. Maybe it can work by overriding `aiosqlite.Connection` but I've never done something like that before. How can I use pysqlcipher3 with aiosqlite?

Answer (score 1):

aiosqlite uses the standard library sqlite3 module -- and that appears to be hardcoded here:

https://github.com/omnilib/aiosqlite/blob/master/aiosqlite/core.py

In addition they've sprinkled all kinds of sqlite3-specific type annotations all over the place, so I'm not sure whether you can even monkey-patch it without causing issues.

Comment: I think you're right. It would probably require a new module. Will accept in a few days.